# How to get a pixel color of ImageView in this hierarchy?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to get a pixel color of middle ImageView.

How to do that?

Here is onTouchEvent method of Activity.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    int pixel = bim_Map.getPixel(x, y);

    // How to get a pixel color of ImageView1?

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :

            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Following is diagram.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: use ImageView.getImageMatrix() and then invert it

Comment: with the invert()ed Matrix you can call mapPoints then

Comment: and with mapped point you can finally call Bitmap.getPixel

Answer (score -1):

Apply a new OnTouchListener() to your ImageView1, for example:

```
ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
imgview1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    int pixel = imgview1.getPixel(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    return true;
                }
});
```